# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'. flutter 3.0.2

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

**I am trying to run a new flutter project on android v3.0.2 and this happens**

****FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.****

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find gradle-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find builder-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/7.1.2/builder-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find bundletool-1.8.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.8.0/bundletool-1.8.0.jar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 869ms

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can't run the app on android, when I click run for the first time it downloads several of the gradle dependencies but ends with that error message, and when I run gradle tasks or gradle build via terminal I get the same error